# Как задать путь переменной окружения в Windows через CMD, чтобы её путь был относительным?

Tags: windows, cmd

Привожу пример:

*У меня уже есть переменная окружения с именем **Myfolder** и путем "C:\Users\user_name\Desktop\New folder".*

*Я хочу создать новую переменную окружения, чтобы её путь всегда зависил от переменной **Myfolder**:*
`setx Mysubfolder "%Myfolder%\Subfolder"`

*Но когда я изменю путь переменной **Myfolder**, то путь **Mysubfolder** не изменится автоматически, потому что он прописывается как абсолютный путь при создании.*

**Как создать Mysubfolder, чтобы её путь был прописан как "%Myfolder%\Subfolder" и всегда вычислялся?**